# Comparing Checkbox Field Values of Two Unrelated Objects Using Map in Salesforce Apex Trigger

Tags: trigger, custom-metadata

I am trying to get field values of a Custom Metadata Type and compare to same field values in another custom object. If combination of checkbox values in custom object matches one of the combinations in custom metadata type, a string field in custom object must be updated to the value of string field in custom metadata type.

Please take note that checkboxes in custom object are updated by process builder, so I used both after insert and after update.

Originally, string field in custom object is blank and will only be updated once combination of checkbox values between custom metadata type and custom object match.

Sample below is what I am trying to achieve:

Custom metadata type record:

```
AbeforeDate__c = true;
AafterDate__c = false
BbeforeDate__c = true
BafterDate__c = false
String_Field__c = 'a042x000009i7DbAAI'
```

Custom object record:

```
AbeforeDate__c = true
AafterDate__c = false
BbeforeDate__c = true
BafterDate__c = false
```

If set of checkboxes match each other, `String_Field__c` in custom object must be updated to `a042x000009i7DbAAI` also.

Below is what I achieved so far:

```
trigger CustObjTrigger on Custom_Object__c (after insert, after update)
{

    List<Custom_Object__c> customObjectsToUpdate = new List<Custom_Object__c>();


    Map<Id, Mapping__mdt> custMap = new Map<Id, Mapping__mdt> ([SELECT Id, AbeforeDate__c, AafterDate__c, BbeforeDate__c, BafterDate__c
                    FROM Mapping__mdt WHERE String_Field__c != NULL]);

    for(Custom_Object__c custObj: Trigger.new)
    { 

        if(custMap.get(AbeforeDate__c) == custObj.AbeforeDate__c &&
           custMap.get(AafterDate__c) == custObj.AafterDate__c) &&
           custMap.get(BbeforeDate__c) == custObj.BbeforeDate__c) &&   
           custMap.get(BafterDate__c) == custObj.BafterDate__c) 
        {

            custObj.String_Field__c = custMap.get(String_Field__c);
            customObjectsToUpdate.add(custObj);   

        }

    }

    if(customObjectsToUpdate.size() > 0) {
        update customObjectsToUpdate;
    }

}
```

But upon saving the record, it weirdly displays following error:

> **error: Variable does not exist: AbeforeDate__c**

I made sure that field name really exist on the custom metadata type, so I am not sure why it causes such error.

Hoping anyone could help me on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am understanding, you are trying to compare the records of custom object with records of custom metadata and it is based on those 4 fields that you have mentioned. In such case, you might need another loop i.e. you will have to loop through custom metadata records as well to compare those records.

```
Map<Id, Mapping__mdt> custMap = new Map<Id, Mapping__mdt> ([SELECT Id, AbeforeDate__c, AafterDate__c, BbeforeDate__c, BafterDate__c
                    FROM Mapping__mdt WHERE String_Field__c != NULL]);

for(Custom_Object__c custObj: Trigger.new) {
    for(Mapping__mdt cust : custMap.values()){
        if(cust.AbeforeDate__c == custObj.AbeforeDate__c &&
               cust.AafterDate__c == custObj.AafterDate__c) &&
               cust.BbeforeDate__c == custObj.BbeforeDate__c) &&   
               cust.BafterDate__c == custObj.BafterDate__c) 
        {

            custObj.String_Field__c = cust.String_Field__c;
            customObjectsToUpdate.add(custObj);   

        }
    }
}
```

Another option would be to create your custom metadata map in such a way that you can compare it in one go i.e. create a map of custom metadata with key as something which can be compared from your custom object records which in your case would be four fields.

```
Map<Id, Mapping__mdt> custMap = new Map<Id, Mapping__mdt> ();
for(Mapping__mdt cust : [SELECT Id, AbeforeDate__c, AafterDate__c, BbeforeDate__c, BafterDate__c
                    FROM Mapping__mdt WHERE String_Field__c != NULL]){
    custMap.put(string.valueOf(cust.AbeforeDate__c) + '-' + string.valueOf(cust.AafterDate__c) 
                    + '-' + string.valueOf(cust.BbeforeDate__c) + '-' + string.valueOf(cust.BafterDate__c), cust);              
}

for(Custom_Object__c custObj: Trigger.new){ 
    if(custMap.containsKey(string.valueOf(custObj.AbeforeDate__c) + '-' + string.valueOf(custObj.AafterDate__c)
        + '-' + string.valueOf(custObj.BbeforeDate__c) + '-' + string.valueOf(custObj.BafterDate__c)))
    {
        string stringField = custMap.get(string.valueOf(custObj.AbeforeDate__c) + '-' + string.valueOf(custObj.AafterDate__c)
                                    + '-' + string.valueOf(custObj.BbeforeDate__c) + '-' + string.valueOf(custObj.BafterDate__c)).String_Field__c;
        custObj.String_Field__c = stringField;
        customObjectsToUpdate.add(custObj);   

    }
}
```

Comment: Upon trying your first approach, field values have been compared successfully without errors. I'm still learning how to use Maps correctly. Kind of confusing at first, but hopefully I can have progress on it. Thank you very much :)